# Prevent home and other buttons to close alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm working on a security app which user can remotely start alarm mode so the phone starts ringing. An alert dialog shows up and requests the password. the alert dialog only should be stopped when password entered. But its also down by using home key or recent apps key. I could only use alert.setCancelable(false) to prevent using back button.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply setCancelable(false) for your dialog and in your custom dialog class call getDialog().dismiss() when the correct password is entered, that should do the trick. The user will be unable to tap out of the dialog box as well as back out.

Comment: Home button still closes the dialog box.